# Validate expression in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Needed javascript regex to validate below expressions :

1+2 should return true

1+2+4 should return true

1+2+3+4 should return true

1 should return true

+2 should return false

2+2+ should return false

In above examples I used only "+", however I have operators as "+","-","/","*".

Thanks for your help

Comment: What about `-2`? or for that matter, `5*-2`?

Comment: What have you already tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Your examples are a good start, now try *writing what the rules are in words*. Pretty soon, you've written the regex yourself.

Comment: Also, what about decimals, e.g. `3+2.5`?

Comment: Used /^((?:\d+[\/*+-](?=\d+))*\d+)$ regex...however as you mentioned this wont work if I we have decimals...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this pattern to cover what you posted

```
^((?:\d+[\/*+-](?=\d+))*\d+)$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/106)

Edit: per comment below to allow decimals, replace every `\d+` with `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: This is working...however if we have decimal in it...e.g. 1+2.5 in this case this wont works...plz help

Comment: replace every `\d+` with `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to match if the string begins and ends with a number, so simply:

```
/^\d.*\d$/
```

will suffice for that, but if you want specific operators to be checked as well you could do something like

```
/^\d+([-+/*]\d+)+$/
```

Comment: It seems that your first expression would match something like `111` .

Comment: Slight technicality: `/^\d+([-+/*]\d+)+$/.test('1')` → `false`. And similarly `/^\d.*\d$/.test('1')` → `false`

Comment: @pravin this will not match `123`.

Comment: @vks: you are right...used ^((?:\d+[\/*+-](?=\d+))*\d+)$

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d+(?:[+-/*]\d+)*$
```

Try this. See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qM8bS5/1

Answer (score 1):

I tried to comment, but I can't yet. Since this is Javascript, take alpha bravo's answer and don't forget the start/end characters for regex expressions, i.e.

> /^((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[\/*+-](?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?))*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/

Code below taken from RegexBuddy for JavaScript:

> var myregexp = /^((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[\/*+-](?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?))*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/;
>   var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
>   if (match != null) {
>       result = match[0];
>   } else {
>       result = "";
>   }